# Trouble defining a proper RegEx in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to create a regular expression that matches a process number that has the following pattern #######-##.####.7.09.0009 where # means numbers from 0 to 9. Here is what I came up with after some research:

```
var regex = new RegExp("^[0-9]{7}[\-][0-9]{2}[\.][0-9]{4}[\.7\.09\.0009]$");
```

I also tried:

- /^[0-9]{7}\-[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{4}\.7\.09\.0009$/
- /^[0-9]{7}\\-[0-9]{2}\\.[0-9]{4}\\.7\\.09\\.0009$/

Comment: You don't have to put `[\.7\.09\.0009]` in square brackets or else it would mean a character class.

Comment: So what is the issue?

Comment: You have to double-escape backslashes when using `new RegExp(String)`

Comment: [visualize it and you will see what it actually is doing](https://regexper.com/#%2F%5E%5B0-9%5D%7B7%7D%5B%5C-%5D%5B0-9%5D%7B2%7D%5B%5C.%5D%5B0-9%5D%7B4%7D%5B%5C.7%5C.09%5C.0009%5D%24%2F)

Comment: Your [second pattern](http://rextester.com/WIMEY33208) works using anchors to assert the start and the end of the line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
const pattern = /\d{7}\-\d{2}\.\d{4}\.7\.09\.0009/
```

Regexper is a great tool that I use whenever I'm writing a regular expression, I find it really helps to visualize what the expression is actually doing. [Check it out.](https://regexper.com/#%5Cd%7B7%7D%5C-%5Cd%7B2%7D%5C.%5Cd%7B4%7D%5C.7%5C.09%5C.0009)

For reference, [here is the original pattern](https://regexper.com/#%5E%5B0-9%5D%7B7%7D%5B%5C-%5D%5B0-9%5D%7B2%7D%5B%5C.%5D%5B0-9%5D%7B4%7D%5B%5C.7%5C.09%5C.0009%5D%24) that you posted -- it looks like the main problem is that you are defining character classes in several places using `[` and `]` where you really don't need them at all.

Comment: So I should do `const pattern = /\d{7}\-\d{2}\.\d{4}\.7\.09\.0009/` and then `regex = new RegExp(pattern)` ? Maybe the problem lies somewhere else then because `alert(/\d{7}\-\d{2}\.\d{4}\.7\.09\.0009/.test($('#numero-processo').val()));` returns false. Here is what `alert($('#numero-processo').val());` returns 1111111-11.1111.7.09.009 Shouldn't it be working?

Comment: Nah, `pattern` is a regex literal (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) so you don't need `new RegExp(pattern)`, you can just do `pattern.test`. What you posted is expected behavior though - "1111111-11.1111.7.09.009" does not match the regex (it should end with "0009", like this: "1111111-11.1111.7.09.0009")